# Matrix Algebra - Determinate multiplied by 2?

Tags: matrices

I am aware of how to find the determinate of a matrix but I have come across this question while practising and do not know what it means. Does it mean I multiply matrix M by 2 and then work out the determinate?

If  M is a 4 by 4 matrix and det(M)=6, what is det(2M)?

Comment: If $M$ is an $n\times n$ matrix, then $\det(aM)=a^n\det(M)$, by multilinearity.

Comment: The determinant becomes $2^{4}•6$=96

Answer (score 1):

One of the properties of the determinant is that if you multiply all coefficients in *one* column by $a$, then the determinant is multiplied by $a$.

Since $aM$ is the same as multiplying *all* columns of the $n\times n$ matrix by $a$, you get
$$
\det(aM)=a^n\det(M)
$$